# CSS Module, or Override?

Tags: reactjs, css-modules

Recently I was working on an ui framework that allow to be extended with different css styles on the same functional component, for instance, a video player. I use ReactJS, and webpack as the bundler, and use css module. However, I found that's hard to put another style for the same component, since I use the css-loader with modules. Did anyone have the common experiment with that? :D